# How do I know if the GRPC connection has been lost?

Tags: java, connection, grpc, grpc-java

I have implemented GRPC Client with Java.

```
String host:"192.893.12.11";
int port:9090; 

ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).usePlaintext().build();
```

I wanna be informed when grpc connection lost. How to notify the client if the GRPC connection has been lost?

Comment: Just glanced at the JavaDocs for `ManagedChannel`, it seems there is a [ManagedChannel.notifyWhenStateChanged](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.html#notifyWhenStateChanged-io.grpc.ConnectivityState-java.lang.Runnable-) method - does that do what you need?

Comment: How this method use? Is there any example?

Comment: `notifyWhenStateChanged` may help a bit. Its usage should be fairly simple as described in the [Javadoc](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.html#notifyWhenStateChanged-io.grpc.ConnectivityState-java.lang.Runnable-).

Note `notifyWhenStateChanged` can only detect channel state changes. However, channel state does not necessarily reflect the TCP connection lifetime. The TCP socket can stay open (or closed by OS silently) even if the network connection was broken in the middle. So gRPC can only know that the connection is broken a write on the socket fails.

Comment: Using an RPC's lifetime is more accurate. You can use a streaming RPC if it helps. RPCs are allowed to last as long as the TCP connection they are on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ManagedChannel's `notifyWhenStateChanged` method to get notify when channel state changed,like want get notify when server shutdown,you can try the below code:

```
// create a ManagedChannel 
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(target)
        .usePlaintext()
        .build();

// add callback method
channel.notifyWhenStateChanged(ConnectivityState.SHUTDOWN, () -> System.out.println("server shutdown"));
```

Comment: This is wrong because the first parameter is the current state  not the target state.